# Add .html (dot HTML) extension to custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

Is there any way to add the `.html` extension to custom post types **without plugin** ?

For posts I can use `/%postname.html` on the permalink settings

For pages I can use:

```
add_action('init', 'change_page_permalink', -1);
function change_page_permalink() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if ( strstr($wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct(), '.html') != '.html' ) 
        $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->page_structure . '.html';
}
```

For Custom post types ???

Is there any piece of code similar to the one above that allws me to change or to add the `.html` on the custom post type url ?

Comment: Just wondering for what reason you want to add .html?

Comment: Well, `function post-type_permalink` will throw an error. If you don't receive this error, then you've got something painfully wrong with your debug settings. Also please rework your question with the correct intends on the lines. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser, Is just to know how can I use the same permalink settings on the custom post types. If I set `/$postname.html` for the posts, how can I use the same for the custom post types.

Comment: You didn't read a single line I wrote in my comment, right? Please fix your code. Also `-` doesn't work in function names...

Comment: @kaiser Yes I did, but I'm not Flash, and I have a hand problem, so I can't type as I think or speak

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seem to work:

Create the rewrite rules like `post-type/post-name.html`. You can use arrays to create the rules for just some set of post types instead of doing it for all of them.

```
add_action( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'rewrite_rules' );
function rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $new_rules = array();
    foreach ( get_post_types() as $t )
        $new_rules[ $t . '/([^/]+)\.html$' ] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $t . '&name=$matches[1]';
    return $new_rules + $rules;
}
```

Format the new permalink structure for these post types.

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_post_permalink' ); // for cpt post_type_link (rather than post_link)
function custom_post_permalink ( $post_link ) {
    global $post;
    $type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
    return home_url( $type . '/' . $post->post_name . '.html' );
}
```

And then stop redirecting the canonical URLs to remove the trailing slash. This might need some more work, as you'll probably want to keep the redirection for most cases.

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', '__return_false' );
```

As others said around here, after doing the above you'll need to flush the rules, and that's possible by visiting the `options-permalink.php` admin page in `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks`.

Comment: Oi Vinicius, a good answering practice is to prefix all function names with `wpse_59024_` *(Question ID)* to avoid conflicts of copy/pasta ;) . . . And has the extra benefit of knowing which Answer does that code belongs in our snippets library. . . . . +1 Spot on!

Comment: This code would overwrite any other filters that use the `post_type_link` filter

Answer (score 3):

You could add a rewrite rule for this that supersedes the built-in permalinks, e.g. for a custom post type "product"...

```
add_action('init', 'add_html_ext_to_custom_post_types');
function add_html_ext_to_custom_post_types() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^product/([^/]+)\.html', 'index.php?product=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

(Don't forget to flush your rules either by re-saving your permalinks or using `flush_rules` in the way @toscho notes above).

### Caveats

- I don't think functions like `the_permalink()` would use this, so you might have to add a filter for `post_link` to catch those links. You could also add to the `redirect_canonical` filter to redirect the default permalinks, so that /product/foo and /product/foo/ redirect to /product/foo.html.
- You would need to add addition rewrites for other URLs that your site used, like feed URLs, subsequent pages, trackbacks, etc. The code above would just work for the main Custom Post Type page.

Answer (score 2):

If you would prefer a WordPress plugin to handle the work for you, check out 
[Custom Post Type Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/screenshots/) in the WordPress plugin repository. Tested on WordPress 3.4.1 and it works perfectly.

After activating the plugin, just navigate to Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks.
You can add specific rewrites for each registered custom post type.

Comment: Do not flush the rewrite rules on every page load.

Comment: that code is not working, also if you just copy and paste code from http://xplus3.net/2010/05/20/wp3-custom-post-type-permalinks/ make sure that it works as expected -1 for not testing

Comment: @toscho how do you suppose to do that or to stop that ?

Comment: `flush_rules()` should be called on de/activation only because it is very slow. You can check `$GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->rules` to see if the rules are known already.

Comment: @Michael Ecklund It gives a 404 I does not work. Did you test that code ?

Comment: @user983248 Amateur mistake of not testing the code. Apologies. However, I think accomplishing this task programmatically is quite the task. The plugin solution provided works perfectly on WordPress 3.4.1

Comment: @MichaelEcklund Just to keep the look and flow, pages and posts are already .html, and personally I don't like url's not ending on a file extension or even a trailing slash. The plugin you mention don't work on my case, It makes no difference at all, see here -> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59006/custom-post-types-and-permalinks That's the custom post type where I'm trying to add the .html extension.