# Make a function to run only for CPTs

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

I found [an answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59957/25187) where the author comments in the code that the `post_type_link` filter is (only?) for CPTs. How he/she can be sure that his code will run only for CPTs?

From the Wordpress [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_type_link):

> `post_type_link` is a filter applied to the permalink URL for **a post** OR
>   **custom post type** prior to being returned by the function
>   get_post_permalink.

The code in discussion:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_post_permalink' ); // for cpt post_type_link (rather than post_link)
function custom_post_permalink ( $post_link ) {
    global $post;
    $type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
    return home_url( $type . '/' . $post->post_name . '.html' );
}
```

Comment: If you follow the link on the codex page to the function's source code, you can see exactly where that filter is applied and under what conditions.

Comment: I don't have the necessary knowledge to understand fully that source code, but from my point of view the above code will work both for **post** and **custom post types**, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before returning it's result, [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) applies one of 4 filters on the permalink it has generated, depending on the post_type of the post in question:

1. `post_link`, when post_type == 'post'
2. `page_link`, when post_type == 'page', via [get_page_link()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_link/)
3. `attachment_link`, when post_type == 'attachment', via [get_attachment_link()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attachment_link/)
4. `post_type_link`, when post_type is not one of the above (i.e., a CPT), via [get_post_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/)

Comment: I see a little contradiction in the `post_type_link` description on the WP Codex page. According to the WP Code Reference page, the `get_post_permalink` retrieves the permalink for **a post of a custom post type**, so, from my point of view, the `post_type_link` can't be applied to the permalink URL for **a post** or custom post type prior to being returned by the function `get_post_permalink`, because the last **can't** retrieve the permalink for **a post**. Probably, this is a typo, and guys from the WP Codex wanted to say "a post of a custom post type" in the `post_type_link` description?

Comment: I suppose, you mean the `get_post_permalink`, not the `get_permalink`?

Comment: yes, the description in the codex entry is incorrect and is corrected in the "new" developer's Code Reference entry, [post_type_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/).

Comment: regarding your other comment, no, I meant [get_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/), which has an `if/then/else` at [lines 143-148](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L143) that dispatches cases #2-4 in my answer.