# Wordpress index in subdirectory, blogposts in root directory

Tags: url-rewriting

For our website we want to start a blog in the subdir domain.com/blog but for SEO value we would like the blogposts as domain.com/blogpost1.html . Is this possible in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install WordPress in its own folder as describe above. If you want a blog post to end with .html that is also possible.

The following link provides an answer on how to do this via code:
[Add .html (dot HTML) extension to custom post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59024/add-html-dot-html-extension-to-custom-post-types)

Additionally, if you search the WordPress plugin repository, you'll find plugins that do this as well.