# How to add the .html extension to the category?

Tags: categories

How to add the .html extension to the category?
For Example [www.example.com/category/category-name.html](http://www.example.com/category/category-name.html)

Comment: If you are thinking URLs with `.html` on them are better than the default WordPress URLS, let me say they are not.  But if that's what you're trying to do, there are several questions that have been answered already: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59957/45202

Comment: dear, I want to show .html extension in the category section.

Comment: Would you care to explain why?  This seems like a really poor idea.